LookerStudio calculated field : How to calculate the average age based on distinct code_id values in SQL?
I am trying to calculate the average age from a table by using a calculated field. The formula I wrote is as follows:
ROUND(AVG(YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) - YEAR(date_naissance)), 0)

This works fine for calculating the age, but I am facing an issue where there are duplicate code_id values in the table. I only want to calculate the average age based on distinct code_id values (i.e., remove duplicates).
How can I modify the query to consider only distinct code_id records when calculating the average age?
